# How Create more TextView in RelativeLayout in rows android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

how to create more `TextView` in relativelayout like

[image]

my code not showing 
not like that :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(5, 10, 5, 10);
    params.setMarginStart(40);
    params.setMarginEnd(40);

    for (int a = 0; a < alquran.getindokata().length; a++) {
        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setId(a);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.hitam_pudar));
        textView.setText(alquran.getarabkata()[a] + "\n" + alquran.getindokata()[a]);
        Log.d(TAG, "VerseID " + id_surat +
                " getKata " + alquran.getindokata()[a]
        );
        holder.terjemahankata.addView(textView);
    }
```

Comment: If all 8 text Views are in single layout then this is not possible with normal layouts. Use `FlowLayout` its an implementation of `Framelayout` available on Git.

Comment: @ADM I do not understand what it is FlowLayout its an implementation fo Framelayout, please give a example

Comment: I don't get it, you want it to be scrolled out of screen? you want the 8 `TextViews` at the same row ?

Comment: If you like to scroll use the HorizontalScrollView and put all textview's inside this

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat without scrollView

Comment: @NaveenKumarM without scrollView, Only textview like that example picture

Answer (score 0):

From the image you supplied, I suggest you a non-official Google library [FlexBoxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) for this. You got variety of options to choose from:

- flexDirection
- flexWrap
- justifyContent
- alignItems
- alignContent

and many more!

You can dynamically add elements (TextView, in your case), in `FlexBoxLayout`, and it will get arranged as you need.

Answer (score 0):

To add more textview to single layout you can use library “FlexboxLayout”.

Following is the code to implement this library to your project:

**Add this to your build.gradle file**

```
compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.6'
```

**Add this to main layout file**

```
 <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexBoxLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:alignContent="flex_start"
        app:alignItems="flex_start"
        app:flexDirection="row"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        app:justifyContent="flex_start" />
```

**Another textview file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_green"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FlexboxLayout flexBoxLayout;
    private List<String> List = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.flex_activity);

        flexBoxLayout = (FlexboxLayout) findViewById(R.id.flexBoxLayout);
        List.add("Test Content");
        List.add("Content");
        List.add("Test Content");
        List.add("Test");
        List.add("Test Content");
        List.add("Content");
        List.add("Test Content");
        List.add("Test");


        setView();
    }

    public void setView() {
        flexBoxLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++) {
            final int pos = i;
            final View tagView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_select_intrest_tag, null);
            final TextView tvTag = (TextView) tagView.findViewById(R.id.tvTag);

            tvTag.setText(List.get(i));
            tvTag.measure(0, 0);
            tvTag.getMeasuredWidth();


            tvTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            flexBoxLayout.addView(tagView);
        }
    }
}
```